# Insert into a table with Pl/pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I try to add an UUID value into a table with pl/pgsql. this is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Surrogate_gen"()
  RETURNS uuid AS
$BODY$DECLARE 
uid UUID;
BEGIN
uid:=(select uuid_generate_v1());
INSERT INTO public.Surrogate_Table(wert) VALUES(uid);
RAISE NOTICE 'My UUID is %',uid;
return uid;
END
$BODY$
```

If I run this code an error occured an says:
**Relation »public.surrogate_table« doesnt exist**

but this table exists in my DB. How can I solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that you created the surrogate table with something like this:

```
create table "Surrogate_Table" (...)
```

Note the quotes around the table name and also note that the error message is talking about `surrogate_table`. PostgreSQL folds all unquoted identifiers to lower case but you have a mixed-case table name. Add some more double quotes to get the right case:

```
INSERT INTO public."Surrogate_Table"(wert) VALUES(uid);
```